# This is the first movie without excitement I've ever watched/I watched (I am not sure which is the accurate one)

Tags: grammar, past-perfect

Given two completely different sentences which are

1. This is the first movie without excitement I've ever watched/I watched (I am not sure which is the accurate one) 
   and
2. This is the first movie I've ever/I watched without excitement

Do the two sentences mean the same ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The prepositional phrase *without excitement* will usually apply to the noun/ verb closest on the page ([post-modifier](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/clause-phrase-and-sentence/prepositional-phrases) here explained on the British Council site).

Sentence **1** means you have never watched a demonstration video or an advertisement for furniture polish.
You have never watched a movie which was not designed to excite the viewer.

Sentence **2** means you have never been sent to sleep by a movie because it was so boring.
You have never watched a zero-rated, no stars, flop of a movie before.